# Different line colors ROC "sp" plot `{Epi}` package in R

Tags: r, plot

I am working with the `Epi` package in R, used to generate ROC curves and other test accuracy information, such as sensitivity and specificity.

There is a dataset within the package about the outcomes in patients with [subarachnoid hemorrhage](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00134-009-1641-y).

When calling the following function:

`ROC(form = outcome ~ s100b, data=aSAH, plot="sp" )`

the different lines are difficult to distinguish due to their similar gray color. I tried adding `color =c(1,2,3,4)` or `color.line`/`line.color` without success.

```
library(pROC)
library(Epi)    
data(aSAH)
head(aSAH)
ROC(form = outcome ~ s100b, data=aSAH, plot = "ROC", MX = T)


ROC(form = outcome ~ s100b, data=aSAH, plot="sp" )
```

[image]

I'd like the different lines to be color coded.

Comment: the data is not available , can you please show where to find the data ? I checked the supplementary materials of that paper but I could not find any data

Comment: did you check the "col.grid"? if it is not woking then, one must make a home function for it ,

Comment: data originate from the `pROC` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
res<-ROC(form = outcome ~ s100b, data=aSAH, plot="sp" )
lines(res$res$lr,res$res$spec, type="s", col="red") #specificity
lines(res$res$lr,res$res$sens, type="s", col="green") # sensitivity
lines(res$res$lr,res$res$pvp, type="s", col="orange") # pvp
lines(res$res$lr,res$res$pvn, type="s", col="magenta") # pvn
```

which basically overlay the colored lines on top after capturing the results.
Alternatively, modify the `ROC` code to include `col` option.